# SQL Join and show results if join false

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table - comments. Users can post if not a member of the site but want to show their details if they are.

So if a user comments who is NOT a member I show their posts but don't link to their profile, because they don't have one.

So, in the following query I want to return the rows even if there is no join:

```
select wc.comment, wc.comment_by_name, wc.user_id, u.url from comments wc
join users u on wc.wag_uid = u.user_id
where id = '1237' group by wc.comment order by wc.dateadded desc
```

I want to return:

```
comment    comment_by_name    user_id    url
-------    ---------------    -------    ----
hello      dan                12         /dan
hey        jane                          /jane
world      jack               10         /jack
```

But the above does not return the data for jane as she does not have a user_id

Is there a way to return all data even if the join is null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead

```
SELECT  wc.comment, wc.comment_by_name, wc.user_id, u.url 
FROM    comments wc
        LEFT JOIN users u 
           on wc.wag_uid = u.user_id
WHERE id = '1237' 
GROUP BY wc.comment 
ORDER BY wc.dateadded DESC
```

basically `INNER JOIN` only select records which a record from one table has atleast one match on the other table while `LEFT JOIN` select all rows from the *left hand side* table (*in your case, it's `comments`*) whether it has no match on the other table.

Comment: I'm self learning joins on the fly and thats a valuable lesson right there! Thanks so much! Will accept when it lets me

Comment: see here for [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)